# How to set template registry while using create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, yarnpkg, npx

As far as I know, when running `npx create-react-app my-app --template template`, I can get template from global registry I set. However, I need the CRA template from private registry and other packages (the packages are installed when running `npx create-react-app my-app`) from https://registry.yarnpkg.com/.

I know I can delete `yarn.lock`, change registry and install again, but the template I write is used for our team so I can't ask everyone to do this. And it's really not a good solution.

Can I set registry only for template while running `npx create-react-app my-app --template template`?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

run `yarn config set "@company:registry" "http://private-registry.company.com"`

Problem solved!